# How to secure a WPF app that uses WCF DataService Forms Auth so that the username/password can not be viewed with Fiddler

Tags: wpf, wcf, security, fiddler, dataservice

I have a WPF app that I intend to distribute. The app uses a WCF DataService with Forms Auth. The web site where the WCF DataService is hosted is using SSL and I believe it is properly enabled on both the WCF end and the client end. No Message level security though.

Yet, when I load Fiddler on my dev machine to test, I can see the username and password. Should it be visible to fiddler thereby indicating my SSL Transport is not setup correctly? Or is it that Fiddle is in the middle, and anyone running my app could use it to see the username/password?

I have looked into the Transport and Message based security offered by WCF and it is unclear to me how to keep the username and password from being discovered.

Is it in fact possible to protect the username and password the WCF client (Forms Auth) is using from being discovered by a locally running app like Fiddler?

Is there some other WCF configuration of Transport and Message, or authentication that would protect a WPF client from having the username/password it is discovered?

Advice on this would be most welcome.

Comment: You should use Message security + set Certificate that will encrypt and sign your communication.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt to help. When I set the securiy mode to Message I get an errors saying that the enumeration value must be one of the following: None, Transport, TransportCredentialOnly. I have no problem doing this with a standard WCF service, but run into difficulties with the WCF DataService. Was your advice targeted at WCF in general or specificaly to WCF Dataservice?